# Guzzle HTTP client: Extract plain text or HTML from the response

Tags: behat, mink, guzzle

Does anyone know how to extract html response from Guzzle HTTP client? If you look at the example below, we can get xml and json response easily but I don't know how to get plain text or HTML response string.

[Documentation](http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Response.html) didn't have an option for plain text or HTML unlike `json()` and `xml()`.

```
$client = new Client($base_url);
$request = $client->createRequest($method, $uri, null, $this->requestPayload);
$response = $client->send($request);

$xml = $response->xml(); // For XML response
$json = $response->json(); // For JSON response
$html = $response->????????(); // For plain text or HTML response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

This returns the whole response body as we see in browser.

```
$response->getBody(true)
```

Comment: For which version of Guzzle. Not true in 5.

Comment: I don't think I can remember the version after 1.5 odd year! This is an old post.

Comment: NP, might just be a good idea to mention it in the answer. In Guzzle 5, the above won't work. Instead, you'd have to cast getBody() as a string.

Comment: You can do `$response->getBody()->getContents()`

Comment: Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called  in this line $client = new Client($base_url);